# Append elements from list to one list then next to another

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve this problem, each value in the dictionary can have 5 elements max.
Original Code is:

```
dict1 = {
    "a": []
    "b": []
    "c": []

}
mainlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Expected Output:

```
dict1 = {
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    "b": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    "c": [11, 12]
}
```

edit:
i cant use comprehension or zip() or break. and the solution must have a for loop.

Comment: `dict["a"] = mainlist[:5]`  `dict["b"] = mainlist[5:10]`  `dict["c"] = mainlist[10:]`

Comment: you should say about `comprehension, zip(), break` at start - we can't read in your mind. And we only wasted time for solutions with  `comprehension, zip(), break`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to do it directly

```
dictionary = {"a": [], "b": [], "c": []}
mainlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

dictionary["a"] = mainlist[:5] 
dictionary["b"] = mainlist[5:10] 
dictionary["c"] = mainlist[10:]
```

For more elements you could use `range(0, len(...), 5)` with `[i:i+5]`

```
dictionary = {"a": [], "b": [], "c": []}
mainlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

for key, i in zip(dictionary.keys(), range(0, len(mainlist), 5)):
    dictionary[key] = mainlist[i:i+5]
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also slice list and always get first 5 elements and later remove them - but this destroys this list

```
dictionary = {"a": [], "b": [], "c": [], "d":[]}
mainlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

# you may need to duplicate list to keep original list
#original_list = mainlist.copy()

for key in dictionary.keys():
    dictionary[key] = mainlist[:5]  # get first 5 elements
    mainlist = mainlist[5:]         # remove first 5 elements
```

---

**BTW:** There can be one problem - dictionary doesn't have to keep order (and in older Pythons it didn't keep it) so `.key()` may gives values in different order.

Comment: It's better not to use in-built keywords as variable names. @furas

Comment: @Vishnudev you are right, but it wasn't important detail in this problem. But I changed names in answer.

Comment: It wasn't important in solving the problem, but, it is always better to guide the SO users in the right way since many learn from this platform :) @furas. Glad that you changed it.

Comment: @Vishnudev I visit many questions every day so finally I skip smaller problems. But it is oportunity for others  to describe these problems :)

Comment: Ohk I understand @furas

Answer (score 0):

You can create the group of 5 using `mainlist[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(mainlist), 5)`, once you have the group then using `zip` combine with the `keys` and apply `dict` to get the dictionary.

NOTE: Don't use `dict` as variable name, it is builtin function.

```py
dictionary = {
    "a": [],
    "b": [],
    "c": []

}
mainlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

dict(zip(dictionary.keys(), (mainlist[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(mainlist), 5))))
```

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'b': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'c': [11, 12]}
```

NOTE: It creates a brand new dictionary, the best option is to save the keys in a list then use this method, but if you already have the dict in memory then other answers will do more justice.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an automated generator given a list and max elements,

```
emax = 5                            # Maximum number of elements
num_cuts = len(mainlist) // emax    # Number of cuts to perform

{chr(97+i): mainlist[i*emax: (i+1)*emax] for i in range(num_cuts + 1)}
```